# Self Scrollable text inside CAScrollLayer

Tags: ios, core-animation

I want to have text inside of a CAScrollLayer scroll by itself from starting point to ending point and then reset the animation. However I cannot seem to get a CATextLayer inside of a Scroll layer. I have even attempted to create a UILabel and use its layer as a sublayer to the scroll layer.

Here is the non working code. I do not know what the culprit is or what I am missing.

```
 UILabel *sampleText = [[UILabel alloc] init];

sampleText.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:20];

sampleText.text = @"Hello World";



[sampleText sizeToFit];

[scrollLayer addSublayer:sampleText.layer];


//add scroll layer to view controllers view
[self.view.layer addSublayer:scrollLayer];
```

Here is my try with CATextLayer

```
CATextLayer *numberLayer = [CATextLayer layer];
[numberLayer setFont:@"Helvetica-Neue"];
[numberLayer setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 20, 30)];
[numberLayer setString:@"Hello Wolrd"];
[numberLayer setAlignmentMode:kCAAlignmentCenter];
[numberLayer setForegroundColor:[[UIColor blackColor] CGColor]];
numberLayer.zPosition = 99;

[scrollLayer addSublayer:numberLayer];

[self.view.layer addSublayer:scrollLayer]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One hardly needs or wants a CAScrollLayer or a CATextLayer for this. Simply start with a superview that clips to its bounds, and inside that put a UILabel. Animate the sideways movement of the label and you're done.

Here's a rough sketch:

```
    let w1 = self.lab.frame.width
    let w2 = self.lab.superview!.frame.width
    let w = w1 - w2
    let x = self.lab.frame.origin.x
    UIView.animateWithDuration(5, delay: 0, options: .CurveLinear, animations: {
        self.lab.frame.origin.x -= w
        }, completion: {
            _ in
            self.lab.frame.origin.x = x
    })
```

[image]

Comment: Matt you are a genius... although it would be nice to know why the scroll layer is not rendering the text

Comment: I am having  issues with it staying inside its parent view.. Like in your example the text clips at the edges and stay within the view but mine leaves the container

Comment: and your expression view.frame.origin.x is not assignable

Comment: "and your expression view.frame.origin.x is not assignable" Sorry, that's Swift. You can't do that in Objective-C. Ha ha ha! :) You have to fetch the frame into a CGRect variable, change the variable, and set it back into the frame.

Comment: "Like in your example the text clips at the edges and stay within the view but mine leaves the container" Because you didn't do what I said. The view must be set to clip its subviews!