# Swift: Streaming String

Tags: ios, swift

Currently I use an attributed string in a UILabel to display a multiline label as a UI Component. One of the lines are usually longer than the box and have to be truncated to fit into the box. Is their anyway in Vanilla iOS to create an animated String that floats from left to right to display the full contents

Comment: I give a possibly useful solution here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/29617343/341994

Comment: Thanks that's actually helpful for another area of the application